# Correct Resolver for Akka Based Projects

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

What is the correct resolver to add to pull down akka-streams and akka-http-streams?

I added

```
resolvers += "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"
```

but Intellij still can't pull down the artifacts.

```
resolvers += "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.6",
      version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    )),
    name := "akka-http-test",

    libraryDependencies += {
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.1.5"
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.16"
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka projects are published to [Maven Central Repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/) which SBT includes [by default](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html#Predefined) so there should be no need to add any special resolver. I believe the issue is a bug in `build.sbt`:

Try defining

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.1.5",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.16"
)
```

instead of

```
libraryDependencies += {
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.1.5"
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.16"
}
```